# Could not obtain connection to query metadata org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095600/how-to-connect-to-my-heroku-postgresql-database-from-java), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52356668/spring-boot-error-in-setting-up-ssl-connection), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56369852/unknownhostexception-when-trying-to-connect-to-heroku-postgres-from-local-spring)
does not solve my issue here is the error i'm getting:

```
2021-01-17 18:49:19.469  WARN 22952 --- [main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     
 : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:315) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:51) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:225) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:465) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:264) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:152) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.27.Final.jar:5.4.27.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1847) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1784) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:531) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1159) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:588) ~[spring-context-5.3.3.jar:5.3.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.2.jar:2.4.2]
    at com.springboot.project1.Project1Application.main(Project1Application.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: bvkgnbxlgupmon:c802e8c6e31976c1ce11584fec0961bc604bce0df24501a6dfd2700240c7ba3f@ec2-3-231-241-17.compute-1.amazonaws.com
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:333) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:648) ~[na:na]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:231) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:95) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:213) ~[postgresql-42.2.18.jar:42.2.18]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
```

**Application.Properties:**

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://ec2-3-231-241-17.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d8pv6nkjjc58qb?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory
spring.datasource.username=beggnbxlgupmon
spring.datasource.password=c3402e8c6e31976c1ce11584gec0961dc604bce0df24501a6dfd2700240c7ba3f
spring.datasource.name=d8pv6nkjjc58qb
spring.jpa.database-platform = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
spring.jpa.hibernate.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
SPRING_DATASOURCE_TYPE = org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource
```

Comment: Check security group on  ec2 instance `ec2-3-231-241-17.compute-1.amazonaws.com` make sure port 5432 is allowed to access from  application and try to `ping ec2-3-231-241-17.compute-1.amazonaws.com` to make sure  DNS resolver is working fine

Comment: how do I check the security group on ec2 instance you mean on the heroku ?

Comment: `security group` on AWS website.

Comment: when I ping `ec2-3-231-241-17.compute-1.amazonaws.com` getting timed out

Comment: `curl ec2-3-231-241-17.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432`

Comment: curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Comment: or `telnet ec2-3-231-241-17.compute-1.amazonaws.com 5432` and check security group

Comment: I could not find the security group in heroku do you know where to look?

Comment: its on `https://signin.aws.amazon.com/`

Comment: i'm not sure I understand, why would I login to aws amazon and I don't even have account there and I was talking to you about the heroku db

Comment: As you do not specify platforms in your question, it is assumed that your DB is in AWS and you manage it via AWS.
Where is running your Spring Boot application? You don't mention it in the question

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how is configured your DB Server. Check the options and try the way that fits your case.

The firts aproximation to resolve the problem its checking connectivity with the server, test from your machine, if its posible.

I would follow these steps to solve the problem.

### 1.- First test that the server accepts connection

You need the psql client available with PostgreSQL installation. Try an updated version, this allows you to connect to both new and old versions
If you doesnt time to Install Postgres, you can use a Docker image Only the psql client
https://hub.docker.com/r/jbergknoff/postgresql-client/

If you have the psql client, try to connect.

```
./psql -U beggnbxlgupmon -h ec2-3-231-241-17.compute-1.amazonaws.com
Password for user beggnbxlgupmon:
**psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "beggnbxlgupmon"
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "x.x.xx.xx"**, user "beggnbxlgupmon", database "beggnbxlgupmon", SSL off
```

As can be seen, **your DBA has configured IP restriction**. Maybe your DBA allow connections only for certain IPs range.

Make sure that the IP or IP range where your application resides, it's allowed to connect to the DB Server.

Add the IP address of the SpringBoot application to the pg_hba.conf and make sure that the method is not set to reject. You need to modify the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and put the IP address to allow connections.

Updated

Security Group it's a firewall in your AWS EC2 instance. EC2 instance lives in AWS. Your DB Server is on EC2. Your instance is in AWS created via Heroku.

Additionaly, if necessary, Add the rule to allow the 5432 port in your firewall/Security Group to the range IP or specific IP.
Maybe this help https://serverfault.com/questions/211244/allow-ports-on-ec2-only-for-heroku

### 2.- Make sure that the machine where your application reside, has connection to the Internet.

Some enviroments don't allow outbound connections to Internet. In order to discard the problem in the client. Verify that the application has access to the outside world.

Comment: thanks for the detail reply, I was able to connect using the psql and see my database and tables and able to execute the `select` statement and see my data so it means the connection is going through my psql and also I was able to connect through the broswers `http://127.0.0.1:54115/browser/` so now I'm thinking my application.properties might not be in the correct format ?

Comment: I tested the format of your connection(application.propertie) and it is correct.